# extract data using jq (keys with specific values)

Tags: jq

I have output of repositories in below json format.

```
 "test/repo1": {
    "id": "Repo1",
    "description": "Repo1 Repository",
    "state": "ACTIVE",
    "web_links": [
      {
        "name": "gitweb",
        "url": "/web/repo1/summary"
      },
      {
        "name": "gitiles",
        "url": "/plugins/repo1",
        "target": "_blank"
      }
    ]
  },
   "test/repo2": {
    "id": "Repo1",
    "description": "Repo2 Repository",
    "state": "READ_ONLY",
    "web_links": [
      {
        "name": "gitweb",
        "url": "/web/repo2/summary"
      },
      {
        "name": "gitiles",
        "url": "/plugins/repo2",
        "target": "_blank"
      }
    ]
  },
   "test/repo3": {
    "id": "Repo1",
    "description": "Repo3 Repository",
    "state": "ACTIVE",
    "web_links": [
      {
        "name": "gitweb",
        "url": "/web/repo2/summary"
      },
      {
        "name": "gitiles",
        "url": "/plugins/repo3",
        "target": "_blank"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now I want parse and extract keys which have state as "ACTIVE" so that my final output looks like below. That output should not include repos with "READ_ONLY" state. How to achieve this?

```
test/repo1
test/repo3
```

Comment: [tag:jq] != [tag:jquery]. If you're using the command-line tool `jq` you should remove the [jquery] tag, if you're coding in javascript and using the jquery library you should remove the [jq] tag.

Comment: I am using command line "jq"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
jq --raw-output 'map_values(select(.state == "ACTIVE")) | keys[]'
```

[Try it here!](https://jqplay.org/s/z2RRLqpmAj)

Comment: One point to note. Above work with jq 1.6 . Did not work with jq 1.4 and 1.5.  Thanks